# vs2015 template for cordova - ios simulator

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have installed Visual studio 2015 and template for apache cordova in windows 7 OS. I want to develop applications for iphone. Without using mac system with IOS, can i use my windows and VS2015 to develop applications for iphone?

I am asking for a sort of simulator. Can any one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ripple, but to actually use the iOS Simulator you will need a Mac or use a service like MacInCloud.

There's a [tutorial on setting up MacInCloud](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build_ios_cloud/) for this purpose.